# What is the function substituting class member access?

Tags: python, class, attributes

For example, we have a class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
```

what is the function call to replace:

```
A.a
```

I want to apply it with `map` function.

Comment: Can you be more elobarative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functional equivalent of doing  `class.attribute` is to use `getattr(class, 'attribute')`:

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self, a):
...         self.a = a
...
>>> obj = A(1)
>>> obj.a
1
>>> getattr(obj, 'a')
1
>>>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

> `getattr(object, name[, default])`
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of `object`. `name` must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s
>   attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. **For example,
>   `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`**. If the named
>   attribute does not exist, `default` is returned if provided, otherwise
>   `AttributeError` is raised.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear but if you want to change the value of `A.a` in python it is as simple as

```
A.a = "New Value"
```

From what I've read from the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#odds-and-ends), it seems that you can do that without the need of setter() and getter() function like other languages. I took this example from the link hyperlinked above.

```
class Employee:
    pass

john = Employee() # Create an empty employee record

# Fill the fields of the record
john.name = 'John Doe'
john.dept = 'computer lab'
john.salary = 1000
```